# BibTeX: Defining own styles?

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex, bibtex

I'm using LaTeX with BibTeX to display the literature of my thesis. We have to adapt our work to several custom 'styles' from the university. That's why I want to somehow define my own styles: For each entry type the given style can be different and further, the displaying in the bibliography and in a cite is different. I don't know if it's quite 'easy' to define my own styles in BibTeX so that I could 'invent' new entry types, let's say

```
entryTypeA
entryTypeB
entryTypeC
```

and than define the style of each how to display it in the bibliography and how when citing it with `\cite{}` and how when citing it with `\footcite{}`, etc.? Something like

```
entryTypeA:
bibliography="@Autor, @Title in year @Year, @Publisher"
cite="@Autor, @Year"

entryTypeB:
bibliography="@Autor, @Year, @Title, @Address"
cite="@Autor: @Title"
```

etc. (just examples).

Comment: Are you using biblatex (as the tag indicates?). If so, then you should define your own cite style or bibliography style using `DeclareCiteCommand` and `DeclareBibliographyDriver` directly in latex (as opposed to messing around with *.bst files).

Comment: And if you are not using biblatex, consider switching to it. It allows to define bibliography styles inside of LaTeX. Section 4.2 and 4.3 of the manual describe how this is done.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll look into it. I think I use it, but I dunno exactly right now Oo

Comment: Okay I currently use `\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw]{biblatex} [...] \bibliography{mybib} [...] \printbibliography`. How to it best with the `Declare` commands? Do you want to post a full comment about this and describe how to fully adapt it? Thanks!

Comment: What determines if it should be rendered as A, B or C type? Do you mean entry type as in actual type (book, article, manual, homepage..)? If not, what determines which type an entry is?

Comment: It doesn't matter, either do it as actual type (book, article, manual) or fill in a certain value for each entry type into one of the unused fields of the .bib-file, e.g. the 'address'-field. the latter is more dirty hacking, but for my purpose it's both okay. The final result is what counts :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of implementation that the OP is looking for closely matches that of the new [Bibulous project](http://nzhagen.github.io/bibulous/). With Bibulous, customized styles are implemented with templates, so that for book and manual entry types, one can define bibliography styles with, for example,

```
book = <author>, \enquote{<title>,} in <year>, <publisher>.
manual = <author>, <year>, \enquote{<title,}[, <address>].
```

where I've tried to match the style to the OP's suggestion. Each field in the database file is referenced with the `<.>` notation inside the template. Then, if one wishes to create customized citation labels, one can use

```
citelabel = <author>, <year>
```

or

```
citelabel = <author>: <title>
```

These definitions are placed into Bibulous' style template (BST) file. Many other customizations are available, as listed in the project [documentation](http://nzhagen.github.io/bibulous/).

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem, but maybe my question/answer [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles) is helpful for starters. There are a number of users at tex.sx who'll be glad to answer focussed questions about `biblatex`.

Comment: +1 Bibliography drivers are already type-specific and that would have been obvious to anyone following Caramdir's advice. Maybe he was looking for something like `\ifentrytype` for defining citation commands? Hard to say without a concrete example, though.

Comment: @Audrey: I'd rather answer good questions than delve into guessing games. :-)

Answer (score 5):

You'd probably have to create your own `.bst`. [This PracTeX article](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/fenn/fenn.pdf) contains links to a few resources describing the postfix stack language `bst` files are written in, including `btxhak` (available on CTAN) and [Tame the BeaST](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/bibtex/tamethebeast).

The document "Tame the BeaST" is available on TeX Live by `texdoc tamethebeast` or [at TeXdoc.net](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf)

Comment: And how about another approach in latex itself: Is there any latex command to only fetch a single information for a bibliography entry, like author, year, title or something? If so, than I could write my own cite command which displays the cite depending on the entryType, which I could write into the address-field of bibtex (which I never use anyway) -> Some simple if statements... only the bibliography wouldn't adapt with this approach...!? what do you think? dunno how hard it is to write my own .bst files :( but will check your links now, thanks!

Comment: @Marc: No, AFAIK there is no such command. The `harvard` package does something like that, but by defining a command that saves this information in the `aux` file, IIRC. This is done partly by the `bst` file. If you need extra fields, it's probably better to extend the `bst` file than use one of the existing fields in a hacky way.