# How to change output of bibitem?

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing

I wish to write a report with 2 reference lists, one with the references quoted in text, and the other one with my own papers.

I would like the first list to look as usual [1],[2],...
but I wish the second list to be like [P1],[P2],...

How can I do this easily?

---

I was thinking in something simpler. One of the lists is generated with

```
\begin{enumerate}[label={\bf P\arabic*}]
```

and then the entries are listed with

```
\bibitem{paper1} ...
```

so that I can recall them later with `\cite{paper 1}`, etc.

The list appears correctly labelled, *i.e.* P1, P2 ..., but when I call a reference using `\cite` I get [1],[2], which shouldn't be.

Is there a way to get [P1], [P2],... just using enumerate and `\cite`?

Comment: Possible related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25007/bibtex-defining-own-styles

Comment: How would you like to distinguish between the two lists? There needs to be a way to tell LaTeX which entry belongs to which bibliography? BTW: Do you mean to use `biblatex` (your question is tagged `biblatex`, but does not explicitly mention it - plus, you mention `bibitem` in the title)? What is your current bibliography set-up? Would you be able to post a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: You can give an optional argument to `\bibitem`, like `\bibitem[P1]{somepaper}`, does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{article1,
  author = "A Author and B Author",
  title  = "First title"
}
@article{article2,
  author = "C Author and D Author",
  title  = "Second title"
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{mypapers.bib}
@article{paper1,
  author = "M Author",
  title  = "Third title"
}
@article{paper2,
  author = "M Author",
  title  = "Fourth title"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[citestyle=numeric,backend=biber,defernumbers]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

See~\cite{article1, article2}.

\printbibliography


\noindent\leavevmode\hrulefill

\begin{refsection}[mypapers.bib]
Here is a list of my papers. I especially enjoyed writing~\cite{paper2}.

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[prefixnumbers={P}]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

The `numeric` style allows for `prefixnumbers` to be set to any string. In the above example, a new `refsection` is started specifically for the bibliography `mypapers.bib`, allowing for a separate showcase of your papers with the required numbering format + prefix.